# add material-components-web.css via webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, material-components-web

I added the mterial-components-web.css to the header of my index.html file.

```
 <script src="node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.js"></script>
 <script  src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

the css components work great. Now I added a few javscript components via webpack. Now I thouhgt I could add all vai webpack into my bundle.js.

```
import 'material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.js';
```

no error, but no styles loaded! wheres the problem?

regards

my webpack config.

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
       {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./build"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to pin down the exact cause without looking at webpack config.

Nevertheless, CSS needs two loaders as suggested in [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css). I can only guess that the loaders are not in place.

One can use inline import too as explained [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline)

Though not near to what you are trying feel free to scan through [this](https://github.com/rakcheru/webpack-bootstrap) simple code that have. It basically has bootstrap css bundled via webpack. Note, however though, i have used `require()` and not `import`. Shouldnt be difficult to switch with proper js precompiler added in webpack config.

Comment: ok, you're right I switch to  require ('./../node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.js'); now it loads corretly, but the window.mdc.autoInit() didn't know mdc! how can I load the script correctly? I paste my webpack.config in the original post.

Comment: Looking at the config, the bundled code is placed in `dist` folder. The devServer is serving from `build` is that expected ? The `index.html` is not processed by webpack. That would mean its your reposbility to include the scripts (i.e. the ones bundled by webpack : `bundle.js`. However, i would suggest you use `html-webpack-pugin`. Thaat would make your life easier as webpack will copy the index.html to `dist` and also insert the script tags too. Refer : https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/ https://github.com/rakcheru/webpack-bootstrap/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: As you can see, there are no script tags in https://github.com/rakcheru/webpack-bootstrap/blob/master/src/index.html . Thats because webpack does the work for you.